# Nexmo API does not recognize number

Tags: c#, vonage

I am trying to link my phone number to use and test Nexmo.
All I am getting is

**Number can contain digits and may include any or all of the following: white space, -,+, (, ).**

I searched for a while and I am sure that I am using correct format.

nexmo link:app [381000000000] [app id]

I am not able to connect my number to the app that I create. Tried to do it from Vonage UI but still no luck. Checked for number multiple times, checked Number API and everything seems valid, after I try again, the same message is displayed.

Any advices here?

Answer (score 0):

Some more debugging could be helpful to determine if the number was indeed linked to your application. With the Nexmo CLI you can see the numbers associated with the application ID by executing:

```
nexmo app:numbers [app_id]
```

If you would like more details on the specific numbers you can add the `--verbose` flag at the end of that command.

This will enable you to determine if the number was successfully added to the application or not.

If the number was not successfully added to your application, you need to confirm that you successfully purchased the provisioned number from Vonage (formerly Nexmo).

You can check the numbers associated with your account with the CLI by executing:

```
nexmo numbers:list
```

Once again, you can include the flag `--verbose` to get more details on the number.

If you do not see the number you are attempting to link to your application in that list then you did not succeed in purchasing it or did not try to purchase it yet.

You can buy the number using the CLI as well by executing:

```
nexmo number:buy [number]
```

The CLI will prompt you to confirm your purchase and output a success message after.

If, though, you do see the number in your account and you are still unable to link it to your application, please reach out to support@vonage.com and they can investigate the specifics of your account and help resolve your account issue.

Comment: I used nexmo app:numbers [app_id]

Comment: What was the result from running `app:numbers [app_id]`? Did you see the provisioned Vonage number you want to link there?